# Por ícone em JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Seria possível por **ícones** na aplicação executável através de código?

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível:

```
URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("/some/package/favicon.png") ;

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

Ou criando um tipo `Imagem` através da classe [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html), adicionada no java-7 :

```
Image imagem = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/some/package/favicon.png"));

frame.setIconImage(imagem);
```

Fonte: [How to set Icon to JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657672/5524514)